# Adobe Snapshot Feature Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Adobe has a snapshot feature, which I'm using to take snapshots of equations and etc. and making anki cards from it.

[image: snapshot]

I noticed an underline below A in "T**a**ke a Snapshot", so I tried pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it didn't work.
How do I take snapshots after selecting text with just a keyboard shortcut without having to right click and selecting 'Snapshot' every time?
Software - `Adobe Acrobat DC`

Comment: How about trying just the letter "a"? Since that's what's underlined. There's nothing telling you to use the Alt key.

Comment: lol that worked,but my pupose not yer served,as i wish to skip left clicking and opening the context menu,everytime, i was updated the question to reflect the same

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while from when you first posted and maybe you have figured it out by now, but I found an answer that might help.

Go to Edit > Preferences > General > Check "Use single-key accelerators to access tools"

Once this is turned on, all you have to do is type "G" and then the cursor will change so you can highlight and screenshot.